# Moving bootstrap-4 button to the right without messing up format

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I am really new to bootstrap-4 and I made a simple social media website using it. I tried to make my create-post, login and register button to the right by "float-right" but it messes up the format? Any advice would be appreciated.

I am expecting this but to the right
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixJTW.jpg

submit button

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info float-right") }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `text-right` for parent class `form-group` to align the button right side.

```
<div class="form-group text-right">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info float-right") }}
</div>
```

Try the below format:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group text-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the float-right class to the parent div - otherwise you will be floating the button within the div instead of floating the div to the right of the footer.

```
<div class="form-group float-right">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but when I put pull-right there, nothing has changed. Any idea?

Comment: sorry - I am used to bootstrap 3 (which uses pull-right) - you were right with float right from BS 4 - I have amended my answer to apply the float to the div that houses the button

Comment: This is what I got after I changed it to that. Is there any way I can get the button within the content box? https://imgur.com/gallery/ZjfS5SP

Comment: I actually don't understand why it get pushed out the white box in the first place, since it is inside before I add "float-right"

Comment: thats because of the vagaries of using float - you either need to add the clearfix class (or BS 4 version of it) to the footer - or simply apply thge text-right class to the footer. Essentially when you float an item - you need to clear the float to allow proper layout.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't add text-right at the class section so it didn't work, rookie mistake for a newbie student coder, sorry guys